# Selected image's pixel data cannot be reached in PowerPoint Add-in with Office-js

Tags: image, powerpoint, office-js, add-in

I want to develop a PowerPoint Add-in that applies visual effects on the selected image in a PowerPoint slide and insert it as a separate image. Therefore, I need to get the pixel data to process it.

I tried to use getDataAsync function but when I change the CoercionType to Image, I got an error that this coercion type is not supported. I searched the Office-js documents and found nothing to get the image's pixel values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/image-coercion-requirement-sets), `ImageCoercion` only works with `Document.setSelectedDataAsync` method. So this is likely a feature request. Please go to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions) and see if your feature has already been requested or request a new feature there.